# Primefaces 8 - java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException when validate value of primefaces Datepicker mindate

Tags: primefaces, datepicker, java.util.date

I am new to jsf and primefaces. I have an app with springboot, jpa and jsf-primefaces, this one worked properly with version 7 of primefaces, however I just upgraded to version 8 and I have a problem. Changing the value of a datepicker throws the **java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException exception**
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null. Debugging the application I have seen that the exception is generated in the  **org.primefaces.util.CalendarUtils** class **convertDate2LocalTime** method specifically when it tries to do the following cast **date.toInstant (). AtZone (zoneId);**

I will summarize what I think is most relevant, my datepicker code is as follows:

AltaEdicionCandidatos.xhtml

```
<p:panelGrid columns="4" layout="grid">
        
            <p:outputLabel for="fecha_envio" value="Fecha de envío:" />
            <p:datePicker id="fecha_envio" value="#{altaEdicionCandidato.candidato.fechaEnvio}" showIcon="true" locale="es"  pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" required="true">
                <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{altaEdicionCandidato.onFechaEnvioChange}" update="fecha_feedback" />
            </p:datePicker>
            
            <p:outputLabel for="fecha_feedback" value="Fecha de Feedback de solicitante:" />
            <p:datePicker id="fecha_feedback" value="#{altaEdicionCandidato.candidato.fechaFeedbackSolicitante}" showIcon="true" locale="es"  mindate="#{altaEdicionCandidato.fecFeedBackMinDate}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" required="#{altaEdicionCandidato.reqfechaFeedback}">
                <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{altaEdicionCandidato.onFechaFeedBackChange}" update="fecha_entrevista_ini" />
            </p:datePicker>
        </p:panelGrid>
```

AltaEdicionCandidato ManagedBean

```
@ManagedBean(name="altaEdicionCandidato") 
@ViewScoped public class AltaEdicionCandidato implements Serializable  {
private Candidato candidato;
private Date fecFeedBackMinDate;

public void onFechaEnvioChange(SelectEvent event)
    {
        this.fecFeedBackMinDate=((Date)event.getObject());
    }

...getters / setters
}
```

As you can see the component ***fecha_feedback*** has as mindate the value ***fecFeedBackMinDate***(of the type java.util.Date) of the managedbean altaEdicionCandidato, when selecting any date of the component, it throws the exception java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException exception.

The ManagedBean I put it only as a reference, since it does not even run.

Debugging the process, I see that it is generated in the CalendarUtils.convertDate2ZonedDateTime class on the following line:
**return date.toInstant (). atZone (zoneId);**

```
private static ZonedDateTime convertDate2ZonedDateTime (Date date, ZoneId zoneId) {
         if (date == null) {
             return null;
         }
         else {
             return date.toInstant (). atZone (zoneId);
         }
     }
```

I have read that this is because the data type java.util.Date only has hours, minutes and seconds, but it does not have a time zone, therefore it throws the exception.

The call to this method begins in the ***DatePicker*** class where it tries to obtain the minTime variable of the ***java.time.LocalTime*** type using the ***getObjectAsLocalTime*** method.

```
protected ValidationResult validateTimeOnlyValue(FacesContext context, LocalTime time) {
        LocalTime minTime = CalendarUtils.getObjectAsLocalTime(context, this, getMindate());
        LocalTime maxTime = CalendarUtils.getObjectAsLocalTime(context, this, getMaxdate());
...
```

Because the value of the mindate is obtained with the getmindate method, I have not been able to know what it returns

Finally, it is even rarer, that in another view you used the same mechanics with the same components and data types and there is no exception.

AltaPosiciones.xhtml

```
<p:panel id="p_datos_generales" header="Datos Generales" stleClass="panelGridCenter" >
     </p:panel><p:panel id="p_sla" header="SLA"  stleClass="panelGridCenter" >
                <p:panelGrid >
                    <p:row>
                    <p:column>
                        <p:outputLabel for="fecha_asignacion" value="Fecha de Asignación:" /><br></br>
                        <p:datePicker id="fecha_asignacion" value="#{altaEdicionPosicionesBean.fechaAsignacion}" readonlyInput="true"  showIcon="true" disabled="#{!altaEdicionPosicionesBean.reqInfoSLA}" required="#{altaEdicionPosicionesBean.reqInfoSLA}" label="fecha_asignacion" locale="es"  pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" mindate="#{altaEdicionPosicionesBean.fecAsignacionMinDate}">
                            <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{altaEdicionPosicionesBean.onFechaAsignacionChange}" update="fec_comp_env_rec" />
                        </p:datePicker>
                    </p:column>
                   </p:row>
      </p:panelGrid>
</p:panel>
```

The component with id ***fechaAsignacion*** has as mindate the value of the variable fecAsignacionMinDate of the managedBean altaEdicionPosicionesBean, which is of type ***java.util.Date***

I have debugged and it goes through the same validations and methods mentioned but in this case it does not throw the exception.

This is a part trace of the exception

```
 context - java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null
    at java.sql.Date.toInstant(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
    at org.primefaces.util.CalendarUtils.convertDate2ZonedDateTime(CalendarUtils.java:422) ~[primefaces-8.0.jar:8.0]
    at org.primefaces.util.CalendarUtils.convertDate2LocalDate(CalendarUtils.java:435) ~[primefaces-8.0.jar:8.0]
    at org.primefaces.util.CalendarUtils.convertDate2LocalDate(CalendarUtils.java:427) ~[primefaces-8.0.jar:8.0]
    at org.primefaces.util.CalendarUtils.getObjectAsLocalDate(CalendarUtils.java:87) ~[primefaces-8.0.jar:8.0]
    at org.primefaces.component.datepicker.DatePicker.validateDateValue(DatePicker.java:215) ~[primefaces-8.0.jar:8.0]
    at org.primefaces.component.datepicker.DatePicker.validateDateValue(DatePicker.java:211) ~[primefaces-8.0.jar:8.0]
    at org.primefaces.component.datepicker.DatePicker.validateValueInternal(DatePicker.java:163) ~[primefaces-8.0.jar:8.0]
    at org.primefaces.component.datepicker.DatePicker.validateValue(DatePicker.java:126) ~[primefaces-8.0.jar:8.0]
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:988) ~[jsf-api-2.2.20.jar:2.2]
    at org.primefaces.component.datepicker.DatePicker.validate(DatePicker.java:103) ~[primefaces-8.0.jar:8.0]
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1270) ~[jsf-api-2.2.20.jar:2.2]
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:714) ~[jsf-api-2.2.20.jar:2.2]
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:575) ~[jsf-impl-2.2.20.jar:2.2.20]
    at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183) ~[jsf-impl-2.2.20.jar:2.2.20]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1689) ~[jsf-api-2.2.20.jar:2.2]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700) ~[jsf-api-2.2.20.jar:2.2]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700) ~[jsf-api-2.2.20.jar:2.2]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700) ~[jsf-api-2.2.20.jar:2.2]
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:371) ~[jsf-api-2.2.20.jar:2.2]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700) ~[jsf-api-2.2.20.jar:2.2]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700) ~[jsf-api-2.2.20.jar:2.2]
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:403) ~[jsf-impl-2.2.20.jar:2.2.20]
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:266) [jsf-impl-2.2.20.jar:2.2.20]
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:65) [primefaces-8.0.jar:8.0]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1193) [jsf-api-2.2.20.jar:2.2]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76) [jsf-impl-2.2.20.jar:2.2.20]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.2.20.jar:2.2.20]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198) [jsf-impl-2.2.20.jar:2.2.20]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658) [jsf-api-2.2.20.jar:2.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [catalina.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-websocket.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.36]
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:145) [prettyfaces-jsf2-3.3.3.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter.doFilter(RewriteFilter.java:226) [rewrite-servlet-3.4.1.Final.jar:3.4.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter.doFilter(RewriteFilter.java:226) [rewrite-servlet-3.4.1.Final.jar:3.4.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:155) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) [spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) [spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) [spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:130) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:66) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:105) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:123) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) [catalina.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [catalina.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [catalina.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [catalina.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [catalina.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690) [catalina.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [catalina.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [catalina.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.36]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_231]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_231]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:9.0.36]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_231]
[WARN ] 2020-07-24 17:17:27.918 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] lifecycle - java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
javax.faces.FacesException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

Please, I will be very grateful if you could guide me to know why this happens.

Beforehand thank you very much.

Comment: If you create a small reproducible test case or MVCE I can help debug your issue. Use this project to create a small reproducer: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces-test

Comment: Don't convert to java.sql.Date in your model... Bad design. Use the normal java dates not the sql ones!

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for the suggestions ... in terms of design, I have followed the instructions on the official Primefaces page, now with the update to PF8 I see that some things have changed but, the reality is that in PF7 it works correctly. I am trying to make a small example to reproduce it.

Comment: Did you check the imports in `org.primefaces.util.CalendarUtils`? The `Date date` in ZonedDateTime convertDate2ZonedDateTime (Date date, ZoneId zoneId)` is that really an sql one? I doubt it. But since it extends the normal `java.util.Date`, I'm 100% sure **YOU** use `java.sql.Date` somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the cause of this, in my entity model, I did not notice that the date columns had the ***@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)*** annotation, which I understand is mapped as a ***java.sql.Date*** not as a ***java.util.Date***, this is why when you first loaded and referenced the minimum value directly from the loaded object, it marked the error. I removed these annotations and it works properly. Thank you all for your comments

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help, but the first test with prime calendar.

Your `pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"` does not show any information about zone.

Try like this pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ"

If your model property LocalDate , pattern must be only date, if your model property is LocalDateTime put patterns like yyyy-MM-dd

Comment: Hi Armen, thank you very much... in my model property I defined the java.util.Date type, but, i don't understand, why in other view i have the same code and it works...